# Simple mapping on jooq with join

Tags: sql, spring, jooq

I am trying to do a simple mapping of a nested class, but I was unable to understand from the documentation if i should use row or field to map the inner class.

```
            .select(
                Tables.Outer.NAME,
                Tables.Outer.Inner_FK,
                row(
                    select(Tables.Inner.NAME)
                        .from(Tables.Inner)
                        .where(Tables.Inner.ID.eq(Tables.Outer.Inner_FK))
                ).mapping { Inner::class.java }
            )
            .from(Tables.Outer)
            .where(Tables.Outer.ID.eq(id))
            .fetchOne()
            ?.map { r -> r.into(Outer::class.java) }
```

It is probably something silly I am not seeing.

Thanks !

I am getting Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Error while reading field: row ((
select "public"."Outer"."name"
from "public"."inner"
where "public"."inner"."id" = "public"."Outer"."inner_fk"

Answer (score 0):

The [`DSL.row(T)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#row(T1)) overload isn't really type safe, as it accepts all possible data types as arguments, including "accidental" DSL API usage. If you look at the formal signatures of the various `row()` overloads, then you'll see that passing a `Select` isn't really supported.

Collecting subquery results in a `ROW()` like that is also not something I've seen in any SQL dialect. For example, PostgreSQL can't do this:

```sql
SELECT ROW(SELECT 1, 2)
```

Obviously, it can do this:

```sql
SELECT ROW((SELECT 1))
```

But that's just an ordinary scalar subquery. If that's what you wanted to do, then you'll have to turn your subquery into a scalar subquery with jOOQ API, e.g. [`DSL.field(Select)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#field(org.jooq.Select))

```kotlin
row(field(select(...)))
```

However, it seems you're nesting the `ROW` only because you want access to that `mapping()` method on `Row1`. Given that you're effectively joining a to-one relationship, why not just use [implicit path joins](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/select-statement/implicit-join/) instead?

```kotlin
.select(
    Outer.NAME,
    Outer.Inner_FK,
    Outer.inner.NAME.convertFrom(::Inner)
)
.from(Outer)
.where(Outer.ID.eq(id))
.fetchOne()
?.map { r -> r.into(Outer::class.java) }
```